# Generate MySQL JSON_EXTRACT condition with user search parameter

Tags: mysql, json, rest

I have a very special case where users can store their own JSON object for records. The reason is that every user has special objects and data structure which is part of his normal record.

I want to let users search for objects in the MySQL DB through my API. I am using the `JSON_EXTRACT(json_field, "$ ...") ...` syntax or in short the `->` syntax.

Users should be able to make queries like this:
`get /service/resource?a>3 AND b.c="dog" OR b.d IS NOT NULL`
where all parameters (a, b) search on the json field.

First I thought of using a list of parameters, but how should I be able to get the AND, OR, IS NOT NULL operator combining them?

How would you design such a search function for a RESTful API?

Comment: Are you using backslashes (`\\`)?

Comment: Rick I do not get what you mean? Can you explain your comment a little bit more in detail?

Comment: `get \service\resource`

Comment: Thanks for this info. It was a typo in the question. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Google is using "+" for building their queries.
Google query "a AND B or NOT c" -> google.com/q=a+AND+b+or+NOT+c

I will try this approuch.

Comment: `+` is used in urls in place of a space.  (It is not just Google.)